# SYSTEMTIME in qt

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, chilkat

I am a bit stuck at the moment with a little sample project that I would like to run to test some cryptology that I want to use in a main project.

Basically I am using the latest Qt Creator and I have created a simple window dialog. Furthermore, I would like to test the PBKDF2 implementation through [CkCrypt2](http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/crypt2_pbkdf2.asp)

So what I have done is downloading the X64 version of the library and added it to my project folder. I then told my Qt project to use an external library, the final .pro file looks like this:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-06-09T18:09:44
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = crypt2test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        m

ainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lChilkatDbgDll_x64
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lChilkatDbgDll_x64d
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lChilkatDbgDll_x64

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/include
```

I can successfully load the library but I cannot start the application.

My mainwindow.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "CkCrypt2.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    CkCrypt2 crypt;

    bool success;
    success = crypt.UnlockComponent("Just some random text ");

    if ( !success )
    {
        qDebug() << "Not successfully unlocking the library";
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The error message I get in the compiler is:

```
c:\qt\qt5.0.2\tools\qtcreator\bin\crypt2test\include\CkString.h:127: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SYSTEMTIME'
c:\qt\qt5.0.2\tools\qtcreator\bin\crypt2test\include\CkString.h:129: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SYSTEMTIME'
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\crypt2test\include\CkCrypt2.h:429: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SYSTEMTIME'
```

Looking into the files I see:

```
void appendDateRfc822(SYSTEMTIME &sysTime);

void appendDateRfc822Gmt(SYSTEMTIME &sysTime);

// GETSIGNATURESIGNINGTIME_BEGIN
bool GetSignatureSigningTime(int index, SYSTEMTIME &outSysTime);
// GETSIGNATURESIGNINGTIME_END
```

Okay, so it is complaining about the SYSTEMTIME construct. So I look up the [error C2061](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yha416c7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
Basically it says:

> The compiler found an identifier where it wasn't expected. Make sure
>   that identifier is declared before you use it.

Which makes sense, so I look up the [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and try to do :

```
#include <windows.h>
```

But that leads to many more errors in the windows.h file itself.

I use the MS Visual C++ compiler in Qt. Even though I use qmake. I am very new to this and I do not understand it all yet. Furthermore, I have no idea how to fix this, because including the windows.h does not help.

What seems to be the problem here ? Is this an issue regarding my compiler or the constulation that I use a third party app which library is compiled with MS Visual C++ and I am now trying to use this on my Windows machine in Qt with a Windows Visual C++ compiler ?

For any help I am gratefully thankful!

**EDIT1:**
Actually, after a clean all and qmake and build project I have now different errors and none were found in the Windows.h as previously stated. Since there were so many I have made a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OckjL.png

**EDIT2:**
I have adjusted the library that I include. Before this I was using the multi-threaded library of CkCrypt in the Debug mode. I have now included the single realease library. Which is located in the same directory.
When including windows.h I got the errors that things were already defined. So I removed the line again. With this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW4Gk.png
This shows at the bottom that MSVCRT conflichts with other library. It mentions to use NODEFAULTLIB:library but I am not to sure how to do that. Will google and keep this up to date as I process.

Comment: "many more errors in the windows.h file itself" - please post error messages.

Comment: @Riateche I have amended the question with a screenshot of the showing errors. Thank you for taking interest in my problem.

Comment: Are you able to compile Hello World project? Are all your libraries built with the same compiler?

Comment: @Riateche, yes I can compile my projects without a problem. In the readme of the library it says: Chilkat 64-bit Class Libraries for Visual C++ 2012 (VC++ 11.0). In my Qt Creator settings for the compiler the following is configured: http://i.imgur.com/tBB1VwI.png - so I guess that it is the same compiler, since VC++ Compiler 11.0 matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many years ago, Chilkat was originally developed for the Windows platform only, and used SYSTEMTIME for this reason.  In the last 5 years (approx) Chilkat is cross-platform, and SYSTEMTIME no longer makes sense.  To cope with the issue, there is a "SystemTime.h" header in the same directory as the CkCrypt2.h header file.  You could include this to solve the problem.  (However, if WIN32 is defined, you'll probably need to edit SystemTime.h to remove the #ifdef.)

In any case, the methods using SYSTEMTIME are going to be deprecated.  For any method or property that uses SYSTEMTIME, there should be a newer alternative method/property that instead uses CkDateTime.

Finally, Chilkat will test with Qt so that for the next version, (hopefully) Qt out-of-the-box will compile without any pitfalls.